# What is the API URL for a JFrog test drive on obitera?

Tags: artifactory

I have created a JFrog demo environment on obitera (https://jfrog.orbitera.com/)
I am trying to use the REST API but I cannot figure out the full URL path.
I can see the UI on "https://demo-ip/" But I get a 404
for  "https://demo-ip/api/system" am I missing a port number or something?

Answer (score 1):

The root of a REST request in the demo environment is "https://demo-ip/artifactory/api/"